# file_get_contents doesn't work as well as direct string?

Tags: php

Its seems like file_get_contents is not working exactly returning a true string value, otherwise it's different.

For example i'm working on a rest API to which I have to send contents via json. One of theses contents is a xml file content.

When I put the xml straight as a var's value, striping slashes, it works. But if I do a file_get_contents() on a file containing the exact same xml (with or without slashes), It doesn't.

Has someone already seen this happening ? If yes, does some one know how I handle this ? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump()` of both variables to see what the difference is?

Comment: It seems like < & > charaters are encoded differently : 
&quot;&gt;&#10; in the straight one,
\&quot;&gt;\n in the file_get_contents one

Comment: Really sorry for my english, I do my best.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Can you provide a minimal code example?

Comment: I finally figured it out : I was thinking it was file_get_contents which was faulty. Actually it was the REST online api.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question :
Actually the probleme was that when I did `file_get_contents()` on a xml file, it returned html encoded characters when I `echo`ed it.
But if, instead of doing so, I just putted a `$var = "<my xml definition>";` and `echo`ed it as well, the encoding was not the same. Which made me think that using `file_get_contents` or not made a really big difference when trying to make REST requests.
I precise that I was trying to pass via ajax to php, xml definition using json.
Actually it was the api which was not working, because of maintainance. And as they didn't communicate on that I was thinking that I was wrong and that my code had mistakes.
So to conclude : `file_get_contents()` seems to work just fine and as expected.
I hope this clear and long answer wont knockdown my reputation this time :)